# How to adjust my dropdown list (Arrow) and make it rounded

Tags: html, css

am trying to adjust my dropdown list (Arrow) and make it rounded, tried several times, but it does't work.

Is there any solution for my issue?  Thanks in advance :)

[Image of my dropdown list Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utas5.png)

[so my goal is to achieve same rounded arrow in the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3hJ3.png)

below is my code, but when i add (border-radius) or (border) its not working at all.

```
.arw {
    user-select: none;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    fill: currentcolor;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: calc(52% - 0.5em);
    pointer-events: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

Comment: am using react language.

Comment: Maybe use a svg there instead?

Comment: I used svg, nothing happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand that's SVG, you can edit your SVG curve path in illustrator or any other vector graphic editor, here is simple [online tool](https://sean.brunnock.com/SVG/SVGPathGenerator/) which might help. Otherwise you can use HTML + CSS pseudo-classes to achieve that. Here is what you can do:

```css
.arw {
  line-height: 1;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc7ce;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: background-color 0.45s ease;
}
.arw:before,
.arw:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
.arw.down {
  transform: rotate(-120deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1, 0.866);
  transform-origin: 30% 45%;
}
.arw:before {
  transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414, 0.707) translate(0, -50%);
}
.arw:after {
  transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(0.707, 1.414) translate(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="arw down"></div>
```

Just adjust `.trangle` `border-top-right-radius: 50%;` and `.trangle` :after/:before `border-top-right-radius: 50%;`

Rounded arrow SVG:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="87px" height="87px" viewBox="-1.7 -1.7 20.40 20.40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="si-glyph si-glyph-triangle-down" fill="#757575" stroke="#757575">

<g stroke-width="0"/>

<g stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>

<g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <path d="M10.106,12.69 C9.525,13.27 8.584,13.27 8.002,12.69 L1.561,6.246 C0.979,5.665 0.722,4.143 2.561,4.143 L15.549,4.143 C17.45,4.143 17.131,5.664 16.549,6.246 L10.106,12.69 L10.106,12.69 Z" fill="#434343" class="si-glyph-fill"> </path></g>

</svg>
```

Comment: when i applied your code it arrow looks like this see answer my question image.

Comment: @MohammadHassan Have you replaced your SVG with my HTML `<div class="arw down"></div>` as well?

Comment: @MohammadHassan Also, can you include your SVG markup in question for better understanding please?

Comment: its not svg, i just grap the icon from online and i applied the properties. @la_petite_kozel

Comment: @MohammadHassan Got it, ok then can you create a code snippet with HTML+CSS, so I can run it (similar to my).

Comment: its diffecult becoz everyfile connected to each other, cannot justgrap the code.

Comment: <svg width="10" height="6" viewBox="0 0 10 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="3.17499C0.983348 3.59166 0.883348 4.06666 1.10001 4.59999C1.31668 5.13333 1.71668 5.39999 2.30001 5.39999H7.70001C8.28335 5.39999 8.68335 5.13333 8.90001 4.59999C9.11668 4.06666 9.01668 3.59166 8.60002 3.17499L5.92501 0.499994C5.79168 0.366661 5.64601 0.270995 5.48801 0.212995C5.32935 0.154328 5.16668 0.124994 5.00001 0.124994C4.83335 0.124994 4.67068 0.154328 4.51201 0.212995C4.35401 0.270995 4.20835 0.366661 4.07501 0.499994Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.87"/>
</svg>

Comment: @MohammadHassan Updated my answer with SVG code for rounded arrow, just adjust dimensions